# Regex to starts and ends with same character

Tags: javascript, regex, redux

I'm not good with regex and I would like create a regex that starts with a open parenthesis and ends with a close parenthesis. My idea is that from a sentence create a group of conditions as I saved using redux.

For example:

(diametro_nominal=80 AND tipo_fluido LIKE 'agua') OR geonodo=1027

All that is inside () is a group and other is a condition.
All that is inside () are sentences separated by a conditional.

So, I would kike that previuous sentence store it like in this image.

How can create a regex that starts with ( and ends with ), thank for your help.

[image]

Comment: To represent an open parenthesis, you can use `\(`. To represent the close parenthesis, you can use `\)`. To represent what's between the two, I suggest you use a negated character class that excludes close parenthesis, so that you're sure you won't surpass the end of your parenthesis, e.g. `[^)]`. You will of course want to modify it with a quantifier, either `*` if you care about empty parenthesis or `+` otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\([^()]*?\)`

This regex will capture all content between an open and a close parenthesis. If the parenthesis stretch across multiple lines, it will match them; if the parenthesis are nested, it will only match the most interior set of them. Mismatched parenthesis are ignored.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/EoEaDU/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! 
And how can capture sentences that are not between parenthesis?? \!([^()]*?\)

Comment: That's a fair bit more complicated, but can be accomplished with `(?:\G(?:([^()]+)(?:\([^\)]*?\))*))*` - [Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/EoEaDU/3/) This regex will match the text that's not between parenthesis.